# Продукт не сохраняется в БД Django

Tags: python, django, веб-программирование, django-rest-framework

Всем привет. Есть код в `models.py`, по которому часть номера продукта попадает в `checker`, и `checker` возвращает информацию по этому продукту. Эта информация попадает в ту же таблицу в БД, что и номер продукта.

```py
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    state = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    b_info = models.CharField(max_length=255)
 
    def save(self, *arg, **kwarg):
        r = requests.get(f'https://system-one.uno/api/cli/bln_check/?card={self.name[:6]}')
        if r.status_code == 200:
            _r = r.json()
            self.b_info = _r.get('reason')
```

При добавлении продукта, через админ панель, продукт не сохраняется в БД. Почему?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы переопределили метод save,но забыли "включить" в него функционал этого же метода наследуемого класса. Добавьте в конец метода **save** : `return super().save(*args,**kwargs)`